# Is there a way to pause execution of a running Java program in Eclipse on Macbook Pro?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, execution

I use a MacBook Pro. Sometimes I want to pause the execution of a long heavy-duty experiment running on my system because I am on battery or for any other reason. Is there a way to do it in Eclipse ? Or even in Mac OS X itself ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can suspend any process in Mac OS X (or any Unix) using the `kill` command to send the `SIGSTOP` signal to the process.

Find the process ID (pid) for example we'll say it's 9281.

```
kill -SIGSTOP 9281
```

and to resume...

```
kill -SIGCONT 9281
```

To find the pid, use the `ps` command, `ps -a` will list all running processes, your process will be a `java` instance running your app.

Answer (score 4):

You could start the application in debug mode and later pause it before setting the mac osx to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already started the application, the best you can do is to use `kill -STOP` from the command line.  You may need to do this to the eclipse process itself if the application is running in the eclipse jvm.

Comment: aren't the Java process and the Eclipse process different ? Stopping Eclipse would probably just suspend the IDE. Right ?

Comment: @euphoria - I believe that it depends how you configured the eclipse launcher that you used to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is contained (no internet connection, no external dependency) just go to sleep or close the computer. It will be resumed after you turned it on.

Comment: i know. i want to continue using the computer after suspending the java process.